# Understanding how for Loops works when we have ArrayObject(p + j);

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am trying to understand this piece of code

```
for (int j = 0; j < outputArray.size() - 5 -1; j++) {
                double sum = 0;
                for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                    //weighted sum
                    sum += weights[p] * outputArray.get(p + j);
                }
```

In the line Sum where there is (P +J) how does it work?
Now I think every weight ranging from o - 5 is multiplied by outputArray from 0-5 respectively, I mean weight 0 * outputArray[0] etc , so what is the role of j?

Comment: Take a piece of paper, add the values of `p` and `j` in each iteration and write it down. What do you get? Then, put this value back into `outputArray.get()`.

Comment: when you say iteration how many are u talking about ? 5 or the value of j?

Comment: yes I understand how it counts , it iterates the last loops first before there is an increment in first loop

Comment: am I accurate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each loop in the first loop do a loop in the second one (in the second one the value of j will be keep)

Try it out to see what happens:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
        System.out.println(j + "<j:p>" + p);
    }
}
```

That will print:

```
0<j:p>0
0<j:p>1
0<j:p>2
1<j:p>0
1<j:p>1
1<j:p>2
2<j:p>0
2<j:p>1
2<j:p>2
```

In your case:

```
sum += weights[p] * outputArray.get(p + j);
```

Will be executed outputArraySize (outer loop) * 5 (inner loop) and the values of p and p + j will range like: (assuming j = 2 and p <= 2 to make it easy)

```
p=0 j=0 p+j= 0
p=0 j=1 p+j= 1
p=1 j=0 p+j= 1
p=1 j=1 p+j= 2
p=2 j=0 p+j= 2
p=2 j=1 p+j= 3
```